# Add whitespace to start and end of text along with special charatcer

Tags: javascript

I would need to add a `whitespace` to the start and end of the text and sometimes the text will have `+` character at the beginning of text. Sorry I have tried below, but it is not working as expected

For example incoming text looks like :

```
a) "Choose"
b) "+ NEW DATA"


let buttonText = buttonname.match(/^[^\s]+[a-zA-Z]+[^\s]$/);
```

Added my jsfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/scrumvisualize/Lvb5fmuc/18/

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate a bit on your expected outcome? Maybe add a snippit that attempts to recreate what you have tried so far?

Comment: Use `&nbsp;` in your HTML... or assign through `.innerHTML`... or better yet, just use padding.

Comment: I have added jsfiddleofr what i have tried

Comment: It would make more sense to do like `function padEnds(element){ element.innerHTML = '&nbsp;'+element.textContent+'&nbsp;'; }`, but really it depends if you're going to have nested Elements. That would be a problem then. I would just have an HTML `class='pad_ends'` then use CSS `*{ box-sizing:border-box; } .pad_ends{ padding:0 5px; }`.